# Print and submit form at the same time - jQuery.print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

My question is how can I print and submit a form at the same time.

I am using the following code, but if printing takes longer than 2 seconds, it cancels the submit of the form.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveandprint" 
    onclick="jQuery('#printableArea').print() + setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('save').click()}, 2000)">
 Save And Print</button>
```

The jQuery plugin I am using for printing:

```
<script src="jQuery.print.js"></script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What plugin are you using for printing?  https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print?

Comment: I've created a fiddle in order to replicate your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/zrvsxy16/. The submit event occurs after I begin printing or cancel the print dialog...

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is navigating to another page to submit the form, no. If it's being sent over ajax, then I believe so.

If you need the print operation to occur only when the form's submitted, it's better to have it triggered on the page the browser is being directed to. Loading and fetching of resources won't pause if the browser's waiting for the user to confirm a print dialogue.